# json_encode JSON.parse Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, json

My code:

```
function callback(request, prim_key) {
    var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    if (type === "application/json") {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        if (!response['success']) {
            alert("Error!\n\nError number: " + response['errno'] + "\n\nError string: " + response['error']);
        }
        else {
            alert("Update Successful!");
        }
        var els = getElementsByClass(prim_key);
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            if (els[i].type != 'checkbox') {
                els[i].innerHTML = response[els[i].headers];
            }
        }
    } else {
        alert("not a json reponse! check database for errors.");
    }
}
```

It will stop when i call jason.parser, and give me error message below:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < .

I try to console the request.responseText, and get the result below:
update: actually, I realize request.responseText not just contain the data I want below, but also contain the html file in the beginning，I think that's my problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
{"success":true,"ID":"131","Manufacturing_ID":"88888","Sequence_Name":"NDU","Bases":"22","Sequence":"TGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TCTGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TCTGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TC","Tm_C":"55.00000000","nmoles":"26.0","Owner":"Liang","Species":"gallus"}
```

it seems there is not '<' in my 'resonseText'.any ideas, thanks

update: actually, I realize request.responseText not just contain the data I want below, but also contain the html file in the beginning，I think that's my problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"...................
{"success":true,"ID":"131","Manufacturing_ID":"88888","Sequence_Name":"NDU","Bases":"22","Sequence":"TGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TCTGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TCTGG AGA TGT GTG CGT TCT TC","Tm_C":"55.00000000","nmoles":"26.0","Owner":"Liang","Species":"gallus"}
```

> my php code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($pks as $pk) {
$query .= "$pk='$pvs[$i]' AND ";
$i++;
}
$query = rtrim($query, " AND ");
$result = $db_conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//$flag_key='';

if ($db_conn->errno) {
    echo "oops";
    } else {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      $response[$key] = $value;
    //$flag_key .=$key.'-'.$value.'***';
    }
}


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: post the JSON, but it is likely that it is a javscript object.  You can use Chrome's or Firefox's console to set breakpoints and see what is going on with the JSON.

Comment: To abc123's comment, are you sure you're not sending back HTML, either? It would make sense if it can't parse the first character - which would be a '<' in an HTML response. (The equivalent of sending a PartialView or the like in ASP.NET, for example.)

Comment: When you said "get the result below:" I think you forgot to copy the result, so we don't know what it is.

Comment: when I get this, it's usually because there was an error on the server sided script (PHP, ASP, etc.). So if you're retrieving JSON via a server sided language, check that.

Comment: Chirstopher, you are right, I forgot to copy my result. See my updated question, thanks.

Comment: "but I don't know how to solve it." -- can we see the PHP code? You need to suppress "normal" output when responding to AJAX calls.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I just update the php code, can you check it for me? thanks.

Comment: Where exactly is that php code located, inside an HTML file?

Comment: @koala_dev, that php code is in a separated php file (I just show part of the code in this poster), and this php file was called by the javascript code above:request.open("POST", "update.php");

Comment: Where's the html coming from then? what happens when you visit update.php in your browser? Check the page source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason could be you have `ob_start("ob_tidyhandler")` enabled in `php.ini`. If yes, then comment this line to disable it.

[ob_tidyhandler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-tidyhandler.php) seems to be the cause. If you check the modified buffer it returns, which looks exact same as the header of the result you posted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there is no ob_start("ob_tidyhandler") in my php.ini. Where should I find it? thanks.

Comment: following your idea, I add 'ob_end_clean();' before 'header and json_encode($request)' in my php file, now, it's working. thanks